# Kendo grid on the fly translations

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using [i18next](http://i18next.com/) as a translation library in my app. I managed to use it for translating kendo grid messages by overriding the default messages. I'm passing a translated value as title of a field in column definition to make headers translated too.

But our app can be used in multiple languages so translations are done on the fly. Every component (either a custom or twitter bootstrap one) is translated except for the kendo grid (= the only kendo component we use).

I guess it should be possible to reload the grid or something similar to make it display the correct labels after changing the language?

I managed to use:

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
```

This refreshes the data of the grid but it doesn't seem to refresh the headers and command + toolbar buttons. How can that be achieved?